# Another (!) Activity Indicator Issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

Well, after reading a bunch of SO posts on this issue, I still can't fix problems with my activity indicator.  This indicator is in a view in a tab under the control of its own view controller. It has a view with a `UIWebView` which loads a local html page just fine.  The view is loaded with `initWithNibName` and then `awakeFromNib`.  Here's the part I think is relevant:

```
@implementation HelpViewController
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize back = _back;
@synthesize forward = _forward;
@synthesize aI = _aI;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
_aI = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
           initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[_aI stopAnimating];

// Now add the web view

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"Help"
                      ofType:@"html"];

[self.view addSubview:_webView];
_webView.delegate = self;
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {   
[_aI startAnimating];
_back.enabled = NO;
_forward.enabled = NO;   
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {  
[_aI stopAnimating];

if (webView.canGoBack) {
    _back.enabled = YES;
    _back.highlighted = YES;
}

if (webView.canGoForward) {
    _forward.enabled = YES;
    _forward.highlighted = YES;
}
}
```

The navigation buttons work fine.  The activity indicator was placed in the nib, but in the main view, not on/over/under the `webView`.  In the attributes, I have `Hides When Stopped` checked.  If I check `Animating` the indicator is always visible and animated, no matter how I navigate through the `UIWebView`..  If I uncheck `Animating`, `Hidden` is automatically checked for me.  In this case, the indicator never shows up.  So it's either always on or always off.

I've read quite a bit about cases where you need to have the indicator on a different thread.  I'm not sure, but I don't think that applies here (I load a local html page but allow users to navigate off and then back to the local page).  But, I seem to have some disconnect; perhaps it is the fact that the indicator is in the main view but the pages are in the `webView`?  Or I'm not calling things in the right methods.  Or who knows... Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite `_aI` in your `viewDidLoad` and never place it in your view hierarchy, so the object you are sending the messages to is never visible and the activity indicator placed in interface build will never change its state, so thats why its either always animating or hidden.

Comment: OK, sounds like my usual silliness.  But I need some guidance.  1.  In what sense am I overwriting `_aI`?  I need to init the style somewhere.  2.  I should add `[self.view addSubview:_aI];` to `viewDidLoad`?  Thanks!

Comment: @BryanHanson You overwrite it in the first line of `viewDidLoad`. It got already initialized by interface builder, so just remove that line. Or, if you want to do it in code, remove the one from Interface Builder and add it to the view hierarchy manually.

Comment: Thank you.  Dropped that line, added the `self.view` bit listed above and it works properly now.  Many Thanks.  When I start from example code I always get messed up on `nib` vs programmatic approaches.

Comment: @BryanHanson You don't have to call `addSubview:`, it is already part of the view hierarchy when the nib gets instantiated!

Comment: Got it!  If I would trust the nib it handles all!